# How to make a flow chart for multiplying all the elements on an array

Tags: arrays

How to I multiply all numbers in the array, do I need a variable? and what should be the initial value?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following pseudocode:

```
var accum = 1
for item in array
    accum = accum * item
```